# Python: making numbered text files

Tags: python, python-3.4, file-handling

I'm trying to make a number of text files within a loop and naming them with respect to their number like `data1.txt`, `data2.txt` and so forth.

```
I = 0
while I < 4:
    file_name = "data" + str(I) + ".txt"
    with open(file_name, 'w') as L:
        L.write('stuffIWannaWrite')
    I += 1
```

But when I run this code, it says that the file cannot be found:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data0.txt'
```

any help?

**EDIT**

i'm working on a virtualenv for a scraping project..

the problem only arises when the file name is in iteration like,
`file_name = "data" + str(I) + ".txt"` in which `I` is being iterated , 
the code works fine on a simple file name like..

```
file = open("try.txt", 'w')
file.write(main_stuff)
```

i.e text file is being created..

Comment: It ran fine when I tried

Comment: No such file **or directory**. Does your default directory exist and can you create new files therein?

Comment: works fine, check if you have permission to create files in the directory

Comment: i'm doing a scrapy project actually in a virtualenv, does that matter ?

Comment: @nigel222 yes i can

Comment: i've been making text files earlier too, but the but without the iteration,

Comment: This also runs in my Python 3.5.4 and Python 2.7 environments.
I expect that you have a system permission problem of some sort.
Can you post code that *does* allow you to create the files?

Comment: @Prune i edited the answer

Comment: Okay.  What happens with `file = open("data" + str(2) + ".txt")` ?  Take it in stages.

Comment: @Prune yea it's working .

Comment: The traceback you posted shows the error as occurring on line 2.  The code you posted has no attempt to access any file prior to its 4th line.  Therefore, the error DID NOT COME FROM THE CODE YOU POSTED.

Comment: @jasonharper everything is as i posted

Comment: @jasonharper you are somewhat right actually i just checked , the problem was in the code, i made a variable outside the function and used the same variable somewhere else, and again in the file naming i.e. "I"

Comment: @Prune the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code will do the trick.

```
import numpy as np
list1=list(np.arange(10))
for num in list1:
    with open('data%d.txt'%num,'a') as in_file:
        in_file.write("stuff you want to write")
```